# Get a string out of a string? Explode?

Tags: php

I have the following string

```
<embed src='herp.com'  width='240' height='180'  allowscriptaccess='always' allowfullscreen='true' flashvars='volume=94&stretching=fill&file=http%3A%2F%2Fmedia.cdn.com%2FTHEMP%2Fflash%2Ffile.mp4&plugins=viral-1d'/>
```

And I want to get the `http%3A%2F%2Fmedia.cdn.com%2FTHEMP%2Fflash%2Ffile.mp4&plugins=viral-1d` out of it.

I was thinking explode by `=` and then grab the second last value, but this may be error prone (example if they add another `herp="blah"` after the flashvars variable the script would no longer work), is there any other way that is a little more bulletproof to syntax changes around the string I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper method here is to parse the HTML with a proper HTML parsing library and extract the `flashvars` attribute from the `<embed>` tag. If you have only one of these though, you really can just use a regular expression.

The expression will retrieve the `flashvars` attribute, and that value is passed to [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to retrieve all the query string components.  `parse_str()` will call `urldecode()` on them so you don't need to.

```
// Regex gets the entire flahsvars
$pattern = "/<embed[^>]+flashvars='([^']+)'/";
preg_match($pattern, $embed, $matches);

// $matches[1] now holds the full contents of `flashvars`

// Then parse_str() on the result:
$parts = array();
parse_str($matches[1], $parts);
print_r($parts);

// The part you want is in the file key:
echo $parts['file'];


Array
(
    [volume] => 94
    [stretching] => fill
    [file] => http://media.cdn.com/THEMP/flash/file.mp4
    [plugins] => viral-1d
)
```

An explanation of the regular expression used:

```
/<embed[^>]+flashvars='([^']+)'/
```

It first looks for `<embed` followed by any character *except* the closing `>` (`[^>]+`).  The capture group following `flashvars=` will look for all characters up to but not including the closing quote on the `flashvars` attribute and store them in the first capture group `$matches[1]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = "<embed src='herp.com'  width='240' height='180'  allowscriptaccess='always' allowfullscreen='true' flashvars='volume=94&stretching=fill&file=http%3A%2F%2Fmedia.cdn.com%2FTHEMP%2Fflash%2Ffile.mp4&plugins=viral-1d'/>";

// figure out where the params begin (keep the starting quote)
$strpos = strpos($str, "flashvars=") + strlen("flashvars=");
$str = substr($str, $strpos);

// get the quoting char
$delimiter = $str[0];

// first match strtok returns is our param list
$str = strtok($str, $delimiter);

parse_str($str, $params);

var_dump($params);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to do that, take a look at:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

It parses URL's querystrings. Buf you have to remove all the extra content first, of course. Just extract the querystring with a regexp

Comment: Strongly suggest using the array param on it though - to save potential security issues

Comment: Actually that will work perfectly... I don't even need to remove extra garbage.

Comment: What do you mean by array param?

Comment: @Steven: Uhm, did you use `parse_str()` on your whole HTML input? You realize that this works by accident and just packs the leading garbage in a separate attribute? (You might as well follow your unhealthy `explode` obsession.)

Comment: @Steven mario is right, it's a bad practice to use things just because they seem to work. The extra param is an array which will be filled with the parsed data